# Strange Periodic Entity Framework Errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After I have successfully generated my model, and worked with it, I will be in some other part of the project and all of a sudden get these strange EF errors. The solution seems to be switch the .NET Framework from 4 to 4.5 recompile, and then back to 4.0. It will work for a while and then they show up again. What is causing these errors:

> Error 10027: The XML namespace for the conceptual model's Schema element is not supported on this project's target framework version. c:\worl\Gilbane RREM\GilbaneCommon\Gilbane.Common\RREM.Data\GilbaneRREMProdModel.edmx
>
> Error 10029: The XML namespace for the Mapping element is not supported on this project's target framework version.

Comment: Is your project targetted at the .NET 4.0 **Client Profile** by any chance?